# How to add version to my java jar and review it from command line (not using MANIFEST.MF)

Tags: java, jar

I was wondering if there is any option to add version to my jar and being able to review it with some "about" information perhaps, through the -v command in the command line. I don't want to ask the people that are going to use my jar to explode it and look into the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF every time they request information about my software.

Is there any way to add that option when I create my java project and before I build the jar?

I know I can code it as an argument, but I was wondering if there was a built-in option in java

Comment: With maven it's common to suffix your version like `myjar-1.0.jar`, I don't think you're using Maven but you could 'set' the version that way.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean but I don't want just a suffix. I want the option to print a description of the version upon a specific command in the command line or something similar

Comment: If you build with `mvn clean package` it should append the version by default, as far as "about" information that's commonly done through a `README.md` file, or javadocs for code documentation